# AngularJS Error:$injector modulerr

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run a simple CRM app, based on the MEAN stack web-book. Upon loading the page I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=userApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DuserCtrl%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.7%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DuserCtrl%250AI%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A186%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A252%250Ade%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A23%253A1%250Ah%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A427%250Am%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A320%250Ah%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275%250Ah%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A444%250Am%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A320%250Ah%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A275%250Afb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A41%253A35%250Azc%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A463%250Azc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A274%250AZd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A83%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A293%253A238%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A174%253A399%250AHf%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fassets%252Flibs%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A35%253A212%250A%0AI%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0Ah%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A184%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A320%0Ah%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A275%0Ah%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A444%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A320%0Ah%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A275%0Afb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A35%0Azc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463%0Azc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A83%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A293%3A238%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A174%3A399%0AHf%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A212%0A


angular.min.js (line 6, col 416)
```

This is my app.js file (the main app module)

```
angular.module('userApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'app.routes',
    'authService',
    'mainCtrl',
    'userCtrl',
    'ngRoute',
    'userService'
    ]);
```

and my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>User CRM</title>
        <base href="/">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.5/custom/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/cs/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/services/userService.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <header>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-if="main.loggedIn">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire text-danger"></span> User CRM</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/users"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li ng-if="!main-loggedIn"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn" class="navbar-text">Hello {{ main.user.name }}!</li>
                        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a href="#" ng-click="main.doLogout()">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have loaded the local dependencies using bower (angular, angular-route, angular-animate), and the rest of the are local .js files, so I can't really figure out what the problem is.

The whole project can be found at this [Git Repo](https://github.com/Shooshte/API). The angular part of the code is located in the /public folder.

Any feedback/ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inject userCtrl in your app, I could not find it in the git repo you

```
angular.module('userApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'app.routes',
'authService',
'mainCtrl',
'userCtrl',
'ngRoute',
'userService'
]);
```

Angular DI, is looking for a service / controller / factory any component that is names userCtrl, which it can not find.

Angular DI does not look for files, rather components with the string names of your components.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and your services have to be part of your `userApp` module, not separates `MainCtrl`or `userService` modules.

Change

```
// This declares a new module named 'mainCtrl'
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

angular.module('userService', [])

angular.module('autService', [])
```

to

```
angular.module('userApp')
```